# What is the sequence of SessionRunHook's member function to be called?

Tags: tensorflow

After read the [API DOC](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/train/SessionRunHook), I also can't understand the usage of SessionRunHook. For example, what is the sequence of SessionRunHook's member 
function to be called? Is it `after_create_session -> before_run -> begin -> after_run -> end` ?
And I can't find the tutorial with detailed examples, is there more detailed explanation?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can find a tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers), a little long but you can jump the part of building the network. Or you can read my small summary below, based on my experiance.

First, `MonitoredSession` should be used instead of normal `Session`.

> A SessionRunHook extends `session.run()` calls for the `MonitoredSession`.

Then some common `SessionRunHook` classes can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py). A simple one is `LoggingTensorHook` but you might want to add the following line after your imports for seeing the logs when running:

```py
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
```

Or you have option to implement your own `SessionRunHook` class. A simple one is from [cifar10 tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py)

```py
class _LoggerHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
  """Logs loss and runtime."""

  def begin(self):
    self._step = -1
    self._start_time = time.time()

  def before_run(self, run_context):
    self._step += 1
    return tf.train.SessionRunArgs(loss)  # Asks for loss value.

  def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
    if self._step % FLAGS.log_frequency == 0:
      current_time = time.time()
      duration = current_time - self._start_time
      self._start_time = current_time

      loss_value = run_values.results
      examples_per_sec = FLAGS.log_frequency * FLAGS.batch_size / duration
      sec_per_batch = float(duration / FLAGS.log_frequency)

      format_str = ('%s: step %d, loss = %.2f (%.1f examples/sec; %.3f '
                    'sec/batch)')
      print (format_str % (datetime.now(), self._step, loss_value,
                           examples_per_sec, sec_per_batch))
```

where `loss` is defined outside the class. This `_LoggerHook` uses `print` to print the information while `LoggingTensorHook` uses `tf.logging.INFO`.

At last, for better understanding how it works, the execution order is presented by pseudocode with `MonitoredSession` [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/training/session_run_hook.py#L69):

```py
  call hooks.begin()
  sess = tf.Session()
  call hooks.after_create_session()
  while not stop is requested:  # py code: while not mon_sess.should_stop():
    call hooks.before_run()
    try:
      results = sess.run(merged_fetches, feed_dict=merged_feeds)
    except (errors.OutOfRangeError, StopIteration):
      break
    call hooks.after_run()
  call hooks.end()
  sess.close()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explaination.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to have a hook for placing validation on cpu? I have a use case where the validation metrics consume too much memory. At the moment I iterate through the batch with tf.map_fn with CPU/GPU swap enabled yet I suspect that is not efficient.

Comment: Is this the only way to log things to tensorboard inside the TRAIN mode of an estimator?

Answer (score 9):

`tf.SessionRunHook` enables you to add your custom code during each session run command you execute in your code. To understand it, I have created a simple example below:

1. We want to print loss values after each update of the parameters.
2. We will use `SessionRunHook` to achieve this.

**Create a tensorflow Graph**

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(shape=(10, 2), dtype=tf.float32)
w = tf.Variable(initial_value=[[10.], [10.]])
w0 = [[1], [1.]]
y = tf.matmul(x, w0)
loss = tf.reduce_mean((tf.matmul(x, w) - y) ** 2)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)
```

**Creating the Hook**

```py
class _Hook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
  def __init__(self, loss):
    self.loss = loss

  def begin(self):
    pass

  def before_run(self, run_context):
    return tf.train.SessionRunArgs(self.loss)  

  def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
    loss_value = run_values.results
    print("loss value:", loss_value)
```

**Creating a monitored Session with a `hook`**

```
sess = tf.train.MonitoredSession(hooks=[_Hook(loss)])
```

**train**

```
for _ in range(10):
  x_ = np.random.random((10, 2))
  sess.run(optimizer, {x: x_})
# Output
loss value: 21.244701
loss value: 19.39169
loss value: 16.02665
loss value: 16.717144
loss value: 15.389178
loss value: 16.23935
loss value: 14.299083
loss value: 9.624525
loss value: 5.654896
loss value: 10.689494
```

Comment: How can I get the return value of `before_run`? In your example I only saw `after_run`'s effect.