# "Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default session is registered" while using custom SessionRunHook with Estimator API

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm following [this example](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/3_NeuralNetworks/convolutional_network.ipynb) in order to learn how to build a TensorFlow's CNN using Estimator API. In the given example there is a line `pred_probas = tf.nn.softmax(logits_test)` which would be highly valuable for me if I could obtain those probabilities since I'd like to use them in this small code snippet I wrote:

```
def eer_eval(y_true, probas):
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_true.eval(), probas[:, 1].eval())
    return brentq(lambda x: 1. - x - interp1d(fpr, tpr)(x), 0., 1.)
```

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45532365/is-there-any-tutorial-for-tf-trian-sessionrunhook) I wrote my own hook

```
class _EERHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
    def __init__(self, probas, labels):
        self.labels = labels
        self.probas = probas

    def begin(self):
        pass

    def before_run(self, run_context):
        return tf.train.SessionRunArgs(eer_eval(self.labels, self.probas))

    def after_run(self,
                run_context,  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
                run_values):
        eer = run_values.results
        print("EER: ", eer)
```

which I'd like to use during the evaluation of the model

```
estim_specs = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode,
        predictions=pred_classes,
        loss=loss_op,
        train_op=train_op,
        eval_metric_ops={'accuracy': acc_op},
        evaluation_hooks=[_EERHook(pred_probas, labels)])
```

However, the code crashes with the error

```
ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default session is registered. Use `with sess.as_default()` or pass an explicit session to `eval(session=sess)`
```

Is there any way I could save those probabilities to a human-readable csv file during evaluation or make my code snippet work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function `eer_eval(y_true, probas)` is obviously not a tensorflow style. So maybe it's better to let the hook compute `y_true` and `probas`, and give the `numpy` values to `eer_eval()`?

In `_EERHook`:

```
def before_run(self, run_context):
    return tf.train.SessionRunArgs((self.labels, self.probas))

def after_run(self,
            run_context,  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
            run_values):
    results = run_values.results
    print('labels:', results[0])
    print('probas:', results[1])
    # err_eval(results[0], results[1])
```

Comment: Interesting, will try this out